# how to add dots(ellipses) in between the pagination numbers in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a pre-generated html for the pagination numbers , which basically comes from the backend CMS based on the number of items present the html looks something like this

```html
<p class="pagination-numbers">
  <a class="" href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.html"> 1 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.2.html"> 2 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.3.html"> 3 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.4.html"> 4 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.5.html"> 5 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.6.html" class="active"> 6 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.7.html"> 7 </a>
</p>
```

the number of pages may increase based on the number of items, so currently the numbers are displaying  all (eg: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

I want this to not display all the numbers but display a few i.e  a first few and replace the rest with '...' and the last one should be displayed.

i want the pagination to look and behave like this something like this

```
Selected page 1: [1, 2, 3, 4, "...", 20]
selected page 2: [1, 2, 3, 4, "...", 20]
selected page 3: [1, 2, 3, 4, "...", 20]
selected page 4: [1, "...", 3, 4, 5, "...", 20]
selected page 5: [1, "...", 4, 5, 6, "...", 20]
.
.
.
.
.
selected page 18:[1, "...", 17, 18 ,19 , 20]
selected page 19:[1, "...", 17, 18 ,19 , 20]
selected page 20:[1, "...", 17, 18 ,19 , 20]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the assumption you know how to set the current page, and know how you wish to trigger the paginator...

```js
// How many pages can be around the current page
let maxAround = 1;
// How many pages are displayed if in beginning or end range
let maxRange = 3;
// The current page (pass this however you like)
let currentPage = 2;

// The paginator (would suggest using an ID instead)
let $paginator = $('.pagination-numbers');

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Upon page load, we want to set the visible pages
    updateVisiblePages();
});

function updateVisiblePages() {
    // Count amount of pages
    let totalPages = $paginator.children('a').length;
    let endRange = totalPages - maxRange;
    // Check if we're in the starting section
    let inStartRange = currentPage <= maxRange;
    // Check if we're in the ending section
    let inEndRange = currentPage >= endRange;

    // We need this for the span(s)
    let lastDotIndex = -1;

    // Remove all dots
    $('span.dots').remove();
    // Loop the pages
    $paginator.children('a').each(function (page, element) {
        // Index starts at 0, pages at 1
        ++page;
        let $element = $(element);
        if (page === 1 || page === totalPages) {
            // Always show first and last
            $element.show();
        } else if (inStartRange && page <= maxRange) {
            // Show element if in start range
            $element.show();
        } else if (inEndRange && page >= endRange) {
            // Show the element if in ending range
            $element.show();
        } else if (page === currentPage - maxAround || page === currentPage || page === currentPage + maxAround) {
            // Show element if in the wrap around
            $element.show();
        } else {
            // Doesn't validate, hide it.
            // Append dot if needed
            $element.hide();

            if (lastDotIndex === -1 || (! inStartRange && ! inEndRange && $('span.dots').length < 2 && page > currentPage)) {
                lastDotIndex = page;
                // Insert dots after this page, we only have one or 2, and we can only insert the second one
                // if we're not in the start or end range, and it's past the current page
                $element.after('<span class="dots">...</span>');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This might not be the cleanest solution, but it is fully functional and works pretty fast within my testing. You can change the `currentPage` number and recall the function and it will change the pagination to the new `currentPage`.

Comment: i see the dots getting appended using the above code but the positon of the dots is not changing

Comment: @JamanaTarun This code snippet has fixed locations for the dots based on what info you shared in your question; either it's right after 1, right before the last item or both. How are they meant to change position?

Comment: what i mean to say is lets say i am on page 3 i should see [1, 2, 3, 4, "...", 20] , and when i go to page 4 i should see [1, "...", 3, 4, 5, "...", 20] , this is not happening .

Comment: Are you updating the `currentPage` variable? Because I just set it to 2 as a base default, as I don't know your site structure.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const act = $(".pagination-numbers a.active").index()
$(".pagination-numbers a:visible").each(function() {$(this).after('<span>.</span>') })
$(".pagination-numbers a:lt("+(act-1)+")").hide(); // one before 
$(".pagination-numbers a:gt("+(act+1)+")").hide(); // one after


$(".pagination-numbers a:first").show()
$(".pagination-numbers a:last").show()
$(".pagination-numbers span:last").hide()
```

```css
a { text-decoration: none }
.active {font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="pagination-numbers">
  <a class="" href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.html"> 1 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.2.html"> 2 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.3.html"> 3 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.4.html"> 4 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.5.html"> 5 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.6.html"> 6 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.7.html" class="active"> 7 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.8.html"> 8 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.9.html"> 9 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.10.html"> 10 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.11.html"> 11 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.12.html"> 12 </a>
  <a href="/content/go2bank/en/blogs/blog-list-page-1.13.html"> 13 </a>
</p>
```